# Having trouble accessing Metadata in Stripe Customer Object C#

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am attempting to create a solution that will allow me to link Stripe and Discord together so that a Discord bot will auto-kick users when they stop paying for a subscription. I'm working on the framework right now and trying to teach myself how to navigate the stripe API with the free options available to me for easy testing. My first test is just to make sure that I can store Discord usernames in each customer object as MetaData and then use that Metadata for the Discord bot to run kick commands as necessary.

However, I can't seem to get at the MetaData for each customer so that it can be sent to the Discord bot as a string.

For my testing, I've setup a simple checkout session for a product and successfully accessed the customer object by expanding the checkout session but when trying to access the Metadata I get the error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String,String>' to 'string".

I thought I needed to use the multiple level option for expanding different objects but I seem to get the same error as above. I've pasted the code snippet below.

```
var options = new SessionGetOptions();
options.AddExpand("customer");

var service = new SessionService();
Session session = service.Get("checkout_session_id", options);

Customer customer = session.Customer;

string customer2 = customer.Metadata;
```

I'm probably missing something simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Comment: The error itself says what is wrong. Metadata in stripe is of type `Dictionary<string, string>` and you're trying to assign to just `string` variable. Fix `string customer2 = customer.Metadata;` line and read necessary metadata values by `key` from a c# `Dictionary`

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Pirate's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398560/having-trouble-accessing-metadata-in-stripe-customer-object-c-sharp#comment115621493_65398560) 
I found the solution and have added the code below.

```
var options = new SessionGetOptions();
options.AddExpand("customer");

var service = new SessionService();
Session session = service.Get("checkoutsession_id", options);

Customer customer = session.Customer;
var customer2 = customer.Metadata;
string discord = customer2.ElementAt(0).Value;
```

Comment: This works fine, but you can also use `metadata["keyname"]` to get a better semantic representation than using `ElementAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `metadata` by name keys when saved to a `var`:

```
        var service = new CustomerService();
        var options = new CustomerCreateOptions {
            Email = "test@example.com",
            Description = "Example customer",
        };
        options.AddExtraParam("metadata[user_id]", "cooluser123");
        Customer customer = service.Create(options);

        var cust = service.Get(customer.Id);
        var metadata = cust.Metadata;
        Console.WriteLine("Metadata['user_id']: " + metadata["user_id"]);
```